# how to use to proxy in the intranet?

Tags: php, xml, curl, methods

i have an intranet site which is inside only our company and feeds information. i download an weather API from http://www.foreca.com/Philippines/ and hook to my site. the API has a search engine and weather info. but some user with no internet connection can't browse it because they don't have any connection.

my question is how can i make a proxy for my site in order from users can browse even if they have no internet connection and also they can browse the API using my server internet connection.

is this possible?

Comment: This should posted on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know you can write a script that gets the weather feeds from internet on your server(keeping in mind that your intranet webserver has internet connectivity), renders the feeds into xml (say after every 10 mins). Your intranet users will read the rendered feeds located on your webserver. In this case even if your users dont have internet connection still they can get the weather updates.
Hope this helps